# Changing accordion mouseover color and tool icon color

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Is there any way to change the mouse over color of the header of an accordion item ? I was able to change the background color by theming it this way in

/packages/myTheme/sass/var/container/Container.scss

```
$accordion-header-background-color: #009FDF !default;
$accordion-header-color: white !default;
```

But I'm not seeing anything for the mouse over color (which is light blue in the Neptune theme that I'm extending) and also, for the color of the tool icon.

Any ideas ?

Solution:

I've used the solution below to change the mouse over color, and this, done at the theme level

```
$accordion-header-background-color: #009FDF !default;
$accordion-header-color: white !default;
$accordion-tool-background-image: 'tools/tool-sprites' !default;
```

The last line puts back the bright set of tool icons instead of the dark ones.

Comment: Can I give you a specific CSS to change, or you really need the value to customize the theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to your main container (`cls: 'test'`) and add this to your stylesheet:

```
.test .x-accordion-hd-over {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Should change the header color when hover it.

Here is a fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/c8b